# Running two instances of web driver in parallel in windows 8

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use windows 8, selenium 2.42 and FF 27.
So i have some trouble.If ff run when i create new driver

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

a have exeption

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d31c7c56c340d6f45a76976d43506cd6cc', time: '2014-06-03 10:52:47'
System info: host: 'bot-pc', ip: '25.111.126.28', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
```

i want create 2 or 3 parallel instances FF, but this don't work if ff open.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140865/unable-to-bind-to-locking-port-7054-within-45000-ms Do you have `driver.quit()` in your script ?

Comment: No, i don't have `driver.quite()` because i need parallel instances.

Comment: Each browser will be driven by a driver instance. So at the end you need to quit() each of them

Comment: Can i open 3 pages in FF with some sites and work parallel with these?

Comment: NO ! 1 driver = 1 page at a time. If you open 3 pages in the same driver you will have to switch between them, it won't be parrallel. To be parallel you need 3 threads with a driver in each of them.

Comment: i know this =)thx u)so i created 3 streams and in this streams i have web drivers, but they have conflict with port, because all driver use port 7054...in this moment i change port and create new instance (you can see my last comment )...but it don't work and WD connect with FF only 7054

Comment: WHat do you mean by `streams`. Do you mean threads ? Because that's what you should use, threads.

Comment: yes, of course. I mean threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use different port numbers for each of the driver instances. Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver. You can set system property `webdriver.firefox.port` to make firefox driver use a different port.

Comment: okey...i write `
        `System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.port",""+ port);`
       `FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();`
      `fp.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.PORT_PREFERENCE, port);`
      `WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver(fp);` but driver use old port

Comment: @СергейПенцов For me I don't set any ports for my two threads. Selenium assign the two webdriver automatically to two differents ports. You should share your java code where you declare your threads.

Comment: @singe31 can you provide some example?