# not able to run the script in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Attempting to execute the following Selenium script results in a `WebDriverException`:

```
package package1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.close();

    }

}
```

The exception thrown is

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at package1.Class1.main(Class1.java:12)
```

Why is this happening?

Used version- 1.8.0_101 java file 
Neon eclipse
2.53 selenium jar file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140865/unable-to-bind-to-locking-port-7054-within-45000-ms)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the selenium server with the Firefox driver before running the test