# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms, exception using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mozilla, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have the above error in Linux Firefox Selenium Eclipse, I have been trying to install Mozilla Firefox 47.0.1 so that I dont have to use geckodriver(), But I find no way to install this.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/user123/SELENIUM/gechodriver");
FirefoxDriver bd=new FirefoxDriver();
bd.manage().window().maximize();
bd.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

My Mozilla version is 98.0 and geckodriver version is 30.0.

Suggest me some ways to solve this error. I have no idea about versions that are compatible to each other(geckodriver and firefox).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140865/unable-to-bind-to-locking-port-7054-within-45000-ms

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is a typo and instead of *gechodriver* it should have been *`geckodriver`*.

Effectively, your line of code would have been:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/user123/SELENIUM/geckodriver");
```

Comment: still doesnt work.

Comment: Restart your system